# Finding keys that were accidentally set

Tags: animation, rigging

I've been working on a character and somehow I ended up with some keys on the timeline. I've checked the drivers and fcurves with everything selected, but I'm unable to locate these rogue keys. Is there a way to make these visible?

Comment: Can you find them in the Dopesheet? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/editing.html#editing-keyframes

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is showing up in the dope sheet either.

Comment: Upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure. Give me one sec.

Comment: Limit of 30 meg on the upload. Trying to trim the file size down.